# Inversify Tagged vs Named bindings with autoBindInjectable

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs, inversify-binding-decorators

I've been trying to understand the difference between Inversify [@tagged](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/tagged_bindings.md) and [@named](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/named_bindings.md) bindings.  I cannot seem to find any documentation which defines the difference between the two.  They seem rather synonymous.

Additionally, when using the Container's [`autoBindInjectable`](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/container_api.md#autobindinjectable) setting, I am even more confused how/where to define an object's tag or name.  There does not seem to be a way with the `@injectable()` annotation.  What does the object get bound using as an identifier?  Does it use the Class as the identifier?

I did see that the [inversify-binding-decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-binding-decorators) lib adds the `@provide()` and `@fluentProvide().whenTargetTagged()` decorators, but does that then eliminate the need for the `@injectable()` decorator altogether?

The docs indicate:

> ```
> let container = new Container({ autoBindInjectable: true });
> container.isBound(Ninja);          // returns false
> container.get(Ninja);              // returns a Ninja
> container.isBound(Ninja);          // returns true
> ```

However, it does not show/indicate how to use the `@injectable()` annotation to allow for the autobind, other than just the generic docs:

```
@injectable()
class Ninja implements Warrior {}
```

But then how do you define `@tagged` or `@named` bindings?  And is there a reason why to choose `@tagged` over `@named`?  Or is the only way to use the `inversify-binding-decorators` lib?

Comment: Did you find out the answer? I was looking for the same.

Comment: @FAntony No - Sadly, I gave up at the time.